# Can you set a text filter value in a hyperlink?

Tags: filter, connected-web-parts

I have been trying to find information on how to do this. I have a web part page that has 3 lists, and those 3 lists are are all connected via a text filter. The goal is, to create a link in a SharePoint 2013 workflow that navigates to this web part page and dynamically filters for the name listed in the Title field. Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Query String (URL) filter. Pass the parameters from your link and connect the filter to each web part.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what you want. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-Query-String-URL-Filter-Web-Part-to-another-Web-Part-8fd0107f-4889-451b-a7f7-d1996e12a8d1

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not what you wanted to hear, but I don't think you can fill a text filter by the URL used to navigate to the web part page.  I believe the best you could do would be a workflow email that has 3 links to a specific(dynamic) view of each of your 3 lists.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you so much for your response. i guess i need to go back to the drawing board on this one.

Comment: Maybe use a search results web part?